# Render markdown from a yaml multiline string in a Jekyll data file

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll, liquid

When using [Jekyll data files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) I would like to store a formatted description, primarily to that I can have links in it. It works with HTML.

```
- name: Project name
  description: >
    I want to include a <a href="http://foobar.com">link</a>
```

That renders properly in the generated page when included with `{{ project.description }}`.

Can I use markdown instead of HTML? I would prefer to do this:

```
- name: Project name
  description: >
    I want to include a [link](http://foobar.com)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out Liquid supports [filters](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters), but doesn't have one for processing markdown. Thankfully Jekyll adds it's own set of handy [filters](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) which includes `markdownify` so now I can do this:

```
 {{ project.description | markdownify }}
```